# Can ClickOnce update automatically without asking the user?

Tags: windows, winforms, clickonce

I have a client that wants a simple install for a small windows system tray application. They want the application to update automatically without asking the user. The app is small and the update should be minimal in size (most of the business logic and code will be behind a web service).

I have been eyeing Microsoft's ClickOnce technology since it seems built for such things. My question is can it update silently behind the scenes without the user knowing it did so? If not what's the best route to accomplish this? Is there another technology better suited?

I realize that updating without telling the user is subjective, but the client is adamant on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ClickOnce applications update automatically when a new version is deployed onto the server. There are multiple ways to force this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx

Also take a look how to have your own gui to inform users about updates:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this: set `-MinVersion` equals to `-Version`, then your App always will download a new version without asking the user.