# ClickOnce auto update on unmanned server without clicking on install new version buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have created a wpf app which runs on multiple different VMs, which I need to automatically update itself when the app starts up.

The VM's turn on automatically and run the app, so a physical user is not actually on the boxes when the app runs, and therefore I need the app to update itself silently without any human intervention.

I have setup a ClickOnce application, which works great with the auto update part, apart from the fact that I need to accept the install first before it will update itself, which is useless in my situation as there is never anyone actually on the box to do this step.

Is there a way in which I can configure the ClickOnce to always update itself if there is a new version without prompting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can ClickOnce update automatically without asking the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612790/can-clickonce-update-automatically-without-asking-the-user)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in which I can configure the ClickOnce to always update itself if there is a new version without prompting?

Only if the app has been downloaded; accepted; and installed prior by a user.  This is a security guard.

Once installed, updates are automatically downloaded and installed at the *point of launch* (but before running) or *after* run depending on how you configured it.